# grails where to find ApplicationResources.groovy file

Tags: grails, config

My question is a simple one. Where do I find the ApplicationResources.groovy file?

I have researched this thoroughly and all I get is posts related to what goes into the file. Not where to find the file in the first place. From what I've researched I gathered that the file might not be automatically created when you create a new grails app. If that is the case then how do I create it. Everything point to the file being in the grails-app/conf directory but all I have there is Bootstrap.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy, Config.groovy, DataSource.groovy and UrlMappings.groovy. I'm following a tutorial that requires me to insert the following code into the file:

```
modules = {
    application {
    resource url:'js/application.js'
    resource url:'js/jquery.form.js'
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationResources.groovy` is a file you create manually under `grails-app/conf/`. It's just a text file so using any text editor you can create this file.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to do that originally but I was afraid I'd break everything. I also tried creating a new Grails Filter which just seemed wrong. Anyway, thank you!